# Cypress: Is it correct to write "dynamic" tests based on server response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e2e-testing, cypress

Doing an E2E test, using cypress, for a page of my app (react app).

The front-end gets real responses from the real server. No stubbing.

So, the top-level component I want to test makes a request to the server and it gets back an array of items. The items number may vary, depending on the request.

Then, each item is rendered in a card.

Is it correct to write a "dynamic" test?

Something like:

```js
it('should render movies', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route('api/movie/popular*').as('getPopular');
  cy.visit('/movie/popular');
  cy.wait('@getPopular').then(xhr => {
    const resultsLength = xhr.response.body.results.length;

    cy.queryAllByTestId('poster-movie-card').should(
      'have.length',
      resultsLength
    );
  });
});
```

Is there any better way?
Is it correct writing tests this way at all?

Thanks.

Comment: The tests will be more robuust when the test isn't dynamic, but I know from experience it isn't always possible to prevent dynamic tests. I prefer to get to a known/not dynamic situation as soon as possible.

I see you can get different responses, why do you get different responses? Do you get those because you choose a different option/button in the interface? In that case the test isn't dynamic and it is perfectly fine.

It mainly depends on why the length of the response can differ, I suspect it isn't fully random.

Comment: @Mr.J. The size (items length) of the response changes over time as more and more data is saved on the DB.

E.g. I make a call to the DB, today, to get all the movies. The server returns 10 items because that's all the data that exists on the DB.

Tomorrow, I make another call and I get back 20 items, because the admin added more data in the DB.

Comment: Check, so you have 2 options. 1. You fill the DB until a certain trash-hold, so you know that you will always receive X items. 2. Don't care about the length of the list. It is a valid choice to only see if items are returned, without verifying the exact number of items.